# Can you leave empty space in the middle of an electrical panel or do the breakers need to be installed contiguously?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I’m planning a 42-space panel on a new build and I think it would make sense to leave two slots empty in the middle to account for a future device that needs a 2-pole, high-amp breaker.

I did some research and I can find one forum post where someone mentions that’s not allowed for new construction, but I can’t seem to find where it actually says that in the NEC.

Are they wrong? Or am I just missing the section? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NEC states all openings must be closed, it says nothing about having to having breakers in them. Use a little caution when you break out the breaker knockouts in the panel front. Good Luck!

Comment: If you're planning for a "high amp" breaker (EV charging perhaps?) it's best to place it closest to the main breaker.   Also, I agree with Gil that there is no rule that I know of in the NEC that says all breakers need to be next to each other.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that section. I took that to mean you can either leave the tab/knockout on the front in place, or if you break it off then you have to put an unused/dummy breaker in there. Thanks!


@GeorgeAnderson I actually already have EV charging there (and it’s at the top!), but I was considering maybe a hot tub in the future! 

Answer (score 4):

### Large breakers should be *down one side* or otherwise spread around

The reason is "bus stab limits".  That little stab that the breaker clips onto.  I once had a guy who wanted to put a 30/50 quadplex across from a 40/40 quadplex.  Counting that, that's 160A on one little stab.  NO!

Most panels have stab limits of 125A, but really, the smaller the better.

Carrying power a few more inches down that fat bus bar is not a problem.

This also means that crowding large breakers toward the top of the panel is a bad thing.  You are creating a worst-case for bus stab load, *I mean that isn't your goal*, but it's a side-effect.

Your largest breakers should have your smallest breakers across from them.  Think surge suppressors (0A) or 15A branch circuits.

In fact, breaker spaces near the top of the panel (nearest the main) are reserved for things like surge suppressor, generator interlock, and a couple other things that I don't recall. Meanwhile Solar must be at the opposite end of the panel (if you want to exploit the 120% rule). So don't put things there and then be surprised when you have to move them.  (though: surges can share breakers).

### Leave yourself *plenty* of breaker spaces

Because if there's anything you learn around here,  "a panel that is full" is probably the most frequent impediment to projects.  Normally this is where I say "and a needless one since breaker spaces are cheap", but it's actually a hockey-stick graph. 42 spaces is the elbow of the hockey stick, beyond that they are costly per space.

So if you are already near full-up at 42, I might suggest dual 30's.

Comment: Ah yeah, I knew about the stab limits, although I couldn’t seem to find any specs on what the limit is for my Leviton panel. Maybe it’s 125A? I was filling in my 2-pole breakers from left to right, but that’s a good call—I’ll run them down the left side and then put my smaller (20-amp) breakers down the right side. Thanks!